# Возврат к выполнению основной программы после прерывания от слушателя

Tags: android, многопоточность, ui, listener

Здравствуйте,

пишу программу в которой постоянно повторяется обновление определенных данных. 
Время от времени срабатывают различные слушатели и программа прерывается.

Хотелось бы уточнить возвращается ли поток UI обратно в основную программу после выполнения прерывания (от слушателя) к той точке в которой произошло прерывание ?

Заранее большое спасибо всем за ответы.

Привожу упрощенный пример:

```
      /*Объявляем кнопку в основном классе*/
      Button button;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


          /* Здесь ставим слушателя*/

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*Какой-то код, выполняющийся, при нажатии кнопки*/
            }
        });

          /* Здесь какой-то код */

          // Начинаем выполнять основную программу по обновлению данных
          mMainHandler.post( new MainProgramCycle() );
        }
    }



class MainProgramCycle implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {


                /*Код основной программы*/

                 /** Обновить данные через 200 мс  */
                  mMainHandler.postDelayed( new MainProgramCycle(), 200 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Что за случаи срабатывают, что программа прерывается? Без кода не разобраться..

Comment: @АндроидАндроид , привел упрощенный пример программы.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, обычно основная программа и ждет, когда сработают какие то слушатели - тогда выполняется код слушателя, когда он будет выполнен, программа опять ждет срабатывания других слушателей.

Мне даже как то трудно представить описанное вами, но видимо да, после выполнения кода слушателя продолжится выполнение "на чем остановились", так как фактически происходит вызов метода с возвратом к месту вызова.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ. Для наглядности привел упрощенный код программы. У меня программа постоянно обновляет параметры, и я боялся что когда сработает слушатель,  программа перестанет обновляться и остановит свою работы после выполнения тела слушателя. А мне нужно, чтобы она всегда выполняла обновление данных.